# How to convert a new line and a br into paragraph tag

Tags: php, preg-replace, nl2br

A client of mine is using an old CMS and their database contains blog entries that used nl2br() on the frontend to give the illusion of paragraph spacing.

On the backend, there is a simple textarea that allows you to add text.

So for example if you add this:

```
First line<br>
Second line<br>
Third line<br>
```

It display like this on the frontend

```
First line

Second line

Third line
```

How can I look for this pattern with preg_replace so I can make it more like this on the database

```
<p>First line</p>
<p>Second line</p>
<p>Third line</p>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gA6zF8/1 ... Perhaps just this? `/(.*?)<br>/g` (to match, not sure if you literally need a newline or want to do further elaborations)

Comment: Hi @briosheje I get the following error when I try this method: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: that's because it's /m, sorry. in any case there is a solution below, but you just can do this: `$output = preg_replace("/(.*?)<br>/m","<p>$1</p>",$subject);` where $subject is the STRING containing the original database output, and $output will contain the desired output. Also, keep in mind that this will work AS LONG AS there only are <br> tags. for <br /> tags support, you need to add a couple of things. Another side note: keep in mind that preg_replace **uses the eval() php function**, therefore be aware that you might be vulnerable to XSS attacks if you don't properly check the $subject.

Comment: `Function preg_replace() should not be used with unsanitised user input, because the payload will be eval()'ed.` --> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Hi @briosheje - thanks for the feedback. This will be a onetime script that will add the proper HTML to the old entries, so that's good! :D - I tried the idea provided by Kita below, but for some reason it doesn't keep the content within the <p></p> of the first 2 lines, only the last line. Any insight as to why that could be the case?

Comment: Not sure, but this: preg_replace("/(.*?)<br>/m", "<p>$1</p>", $input_lines); should work, as pointed above. Check this one there: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b3W directly tested using preg_replace. (just hit preg_replace in the options instead of preg_match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample PHP that should do what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$string = <<<STRING
First line<br>
Second line<br>
Third line<br>
STRING;

$output = preg_replace("/^(.*)<br.*\/?>/m", '<p>$1</p>', $string);

echo $output;
?>
```

The output comes out as:

```
<p>First line</p>                                                                                                             
<p>Second line</p>                                                                                                            
<p>Third line</p>
```

Here's the regex if you want to play with it: https://regex101.com/r/zY6zO9/1

Comment: Hi @Kita - This looks like it was close. I got <p></p><p></p><p>Third Line</p> - the first and second line does not show up, but it added the correct number of <p></p>

Comment: @Hugo are you trying with the exact input shown in your original question? It should work. The regex link I posted shows that we're matching all of the lines :O

Comment: @Hugo checkout the code sample I posted on runnable. You can run it in the terminal window `php index.php` It seems to be producing the expected output: http://runnable.com/VUpGZ4YgiqAapg4T/so-regex-example-for-php

Comment: yeah everything works. I made some mistakes on my end!